# What happened to the gold?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-series

At the end of the first Bad Company you are given new orders to take the truck loaded with gold and follow the convoy.  Part way down the road you turn off to the right (leaving the convoy) with the members of the squad implying what they are going to do with their new wealth.

However, after playing through Bad Company 2 I cannot see how these two plot lines relate.  Your squad (in the second game) is now a counter-intelligence unit trying to acquire a device.  Its almost like Bad Company 2 is in an alternative universe, or the group changed their minds at the end of the first game, or the theft went unnoticed.

Have I missed anything in game that explains how the group "got away with it" - in that they have the gold from Bad Company 1 by slipping away from the convoy but are still in the army as an active unit by the time Bad Company 2 events begin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no mention at all of those events in BC2. It is the same group, however, it seems DICE just wanted to make the audience forget those events. Makes sense as back in that time they were looking for innovation, and to involve people in the series without previous knowledge.

One can assume they got caught and had to do more work. I don't think they got any kind of wealth as Sarge is about to retire. Had he had money he wouldn't be the Sarge we got to know in BC2.

Comment: After playing through a second time I could not see any mention of the gold.

Answer (score -2):

I just assumed that they stored the gold somewhere, but didn't want to be hunted down by the government for desertion, so they went back to the military. But the gold is still somewhere hidden. Maybe they dumped the gold in certain locations that they would remember, but people eventually found out where the gold was stashed, thus Bad Company 1's Rush was introduced.